# Not running server with browsersync + django + gulp

Tags: django, gulp, browser-sync

The page is loading and shows nothing.

Version:
Python: 3.5.2
Django: 1.10.2
node: 4.2.6
npm: 3.5.2

Gulp run without error:
[image]

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var exec = require('child_process').exec;


gulp.task('runserver', function() {
    var proc = exec('python manage.py runserver');
    console.log('runserver');
})


gulp.task('browserSync', ['runserver'], function() {
  browserSync.init({
    notify: false,
    port: 8090,
    proxy: 'localhost:8090'
  })
  console.log('browserSync');
});


gulp.task('default', ['browserSync']);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to explain how I solved this problem:

I had to open two terminal (and activate virtualenv), in the first terminal I run "python manage.py runserver" and in the second terminal "gulp"

This worked for me

Answer (score -2):

Your goal is to control two processes with a single command, so you need a better supervisor than `gulp`:

```
$ npm install --save-dev concurrently
```

Inside `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "concurrently --kill-others 'gulp browserSync' 'python manage.py runserver'"
}
```

And remove the Django (runserver) task.